# How to create a column of auto_increment values?

Tags: android, sql

I want to create a column of AUTOINCREMENT values in android. I tried the below way of doing it but it failed. I want the column to auto increment itself whenever a new record is added.

I get an exception "Can't upgrade read-only database from version 0 to 25" when i include "AUTOINCREMENT" to game_id.

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Games (" +
                    "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    "game_id INTEGER **AUTOINCREMENT**," +
                    "title TEXT" +                            
                    ");");
```

Comment: Why do you need two autoincrement columns? Is this sqlite? Why are you trying to modify a read-only database?

Comment: There is an option for user to move the items from UI. So i saw an example of how android moves playlist in music player and they used two fields. One is _id and another is a autoIncrement value.

Comment: I think the exception is wrong. I get this exception only when i include "AUTOINCREMENT" to game_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLite, the autoincrement keyword only modifies the behavior of the algorithm that selects the next null integer primary key.  It does not behave in the manner you desire.  Sorry.
The only solution I can come up with is to do what you want programatically and add the unique constraint to the game_id field

[See Documentation Here](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

```
`CREATE table Games (_id integer primary key autoincrement, game_id integer unique, title text)`;
```

This worked in sqlite3, but you should try to catch the error if you enter something that is already in the table.  The other possibility, depending on what you are after, is to create another table.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for the solution i did this way.

1. Create the new row.
2. Use the returned value from insert (rowdID) and do an update on the required field.

   ```
       long rowID = db.insert(games, "url",
               initialValues);
       if (rowID > 0) {    
           ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
           values.put("game_order", rowID);
           String[] args = new String[]{String.valueOf(rowID)};
           db.update(games, values, "_id=?", args);
       }
   ```